# EntityNotFoundException on save function

Tags: spring, jpa

I am trying to save Entity with one to many relation. It throws `EntityNotFoundException` when trying to save the entity

I did some research but not able to find any solution to this

Order Entity:

```
@Data
@Component
@Entity
@Slf4j
@Table (name = ORDER_TABLE_NAME)
public class OrderEntity {

//== Order Details
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
    @Column(name = ORDER_ID_COLUMN)
    private String orderIdGuid;

    @Column (name = ORDER_BOOKED_DATETIME_COLUMN)
    private LocalDateTime orderBookedDate;

    @Column(name = ORDER_STATUS_COLUMN)
    private String orderStatus;

    @OneToMany( cascade={CascadeType.ALL}, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name= ORDER_ID_COLUMN)
    @Autowired
    private List<ProductEntity> products;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = ORDER_ID_COLUMN)
    private List<Followup> followups;
```

Product Entity:

```
@Data
@Component
@Entity
@Table (name=ORDER_PRODUCT_TABLE)
public class ProductEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
    @Column (name = PRODUCT_PRIMARY_ID)
    private String product_primary_id;

    //=== defined by constants
    @Column(name = PRODUCT_NAME)
    private String productName;
```

DAOClass:

```
@Component
@Data
@Slf4j
public class DAOOrderRepository {

    @Autowired
    OrderRepository orderRepository;

    public void saveOrderEntity(OrderEntity orderEntity) {
        orderEntity.setOrderUpdatedDate(LocalDate.now());
        orderRepository.save(orderEntity);
    }

    public OrderEntity findOrderByOrderId(String orderId) {
        return orderRepository.findOrderEntityByOrderIdGuid(orderId);
    }

    public List<OrderEntity> findAllOrdersByEmployeeId(String employeeId) {
        return orderRepository.findBySalesRepEmployeeId(employeeId);
    }
}
```

Repository:

```
@Repository
public interface OrderRepository extends JpaRepository<OrderEntity,String> {

    List<OrderEntity> findBySalesRepEmployeeId(String employeeId);

    OrderEntity findOrderEntityByOrderIdGuid(String orderIdGuid);
}
```

Exception:

```
org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaObjectRetrievalFailureException: Unable to 
find 
com.app.apicore.Entities.OrderServiceEntity.ProductEntity.ProductEntity 
with id 03350d2a-15cf-46da-ba2c-58aeec79db9a; nested exception is 
javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: Unable to find 
com.app.apicore.Entities.OrderServiceEntity.ProductEntity.ProductEntity 
with id 03350d2a-15cf-46da-ba2c-58aeec79db9a
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.convertJpaAccessExceptionIfPossible(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:378)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:255)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:527)
at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61)
at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:242)
at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:153)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:138)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:93)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:61)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy111.save(Unknown Source)
at com.app.apicore.Apis.DAOOrderRepository.saveOrderEntity(DAOOrderRepository.java:24)
```

Each order is a new order record. So when i try to save the order record for the first time, it saves the order data correct. It saves the order data correct for second time to. But on the third time throws exception.

Comment: Each order is a new order record. So when i try to save the order record for the first time, it saves the order data correct. It saves the order data correct for second time to. But on the third time throws exception. It  is consistently failing on third time

Comment: Why are your entites Spring Componentes and why do you use Autowired in the entity?

Comment: I am new to this so was following the general spring component and autowiring for creating objects. I can remove that. Would that solve for the problem?

Comment: Give it a try... Entities must not be Spring Beans!